# Arbitrarily large integers in C#

Tags: c#, .net, python, biginteger

How can I implement this python code in c#?

Python code:

```
print(str(int(str("e60f553e42aa44aebf1d6723b0be7541"), 16)))
```

Result:

```
305802052421002911840647389720929531201
```

But in c# I have problems with big digits.

Can you help me?

I've got different results in python and c#. Where can be mistake?

Answer (score 25):

Primitive types (such as `Int32`, `Int64`) have a finite length that it's not enough for such big number. For example:

```
Data type                                     Maximum positive value
Int32                                                  2,147,483,647
UInt32                                                 4,294,967,295
Int64                                      9,223,372,036,854,775,808
UInt64                                    18,446,744,073,709,551,615
Your number      305,802,052,421,002,911,840,647,389,720,929,531,201
```

In this case to represent that number you would need 128 bits. With .NET Framework 4.0 there is a new data type for arbitrarily sized integer numbers [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx). You do not need to specify any size because it'll be *inferred* by the number itself (it means that you may even get an `OutOfMemoryException` when you perform, for example, a multiplication of two very big numbers).

To come back to your question, first parse your hexadecimal number:

```
string bigNumberAsText = "e60f553e42aa44aebf1d6723b0be7541";
BigInteger bigNumber = BigInteger.Parse(bigNumberAsText,
    NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
```

Then simply print it to console:

```
Console.WriteLine(bigNumber.ToString());
```

You may be interested to calculate how many bits you need to represent an arbitrary number, use this function (if I remember well original implementation comes from C Numerical Recipes):

```
public static uint GetNeededBitsToRepresentInteger(BigInteger value)
{
   uint neededBits = 0;
   while (value != 0)
   {
      value >>= 1;
      ++neededBits;
   }

   return neededBits;
}
```

Then to calculate the required size of a number wrote as string:

```
public static uint GetNeededBitsToRepresentInteger(string value,
   NumberStyles numberStyle = NumberStyles.None)
{
   return GetNeededBitsToRepresentInteger(
      BigInteger.Parse(value, numberStyle));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! But returns wrong result, it's question of time. perhaps...=)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to be able to use larger numbers there is [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) which has a lot of digits.

Answer (score 1):

To find the number of bits you need to store a `BigInteger N`, you can use:

```
BigInteger N = ...;
int nBits = Mathf.CeilToInt((float)BigInteger.Log(N, 2.0));
```