# TryParse leading zeros

Tags: c#, tryparse

I need to parse a number with leading zeros:

```
if (uint.TryParse(strNum, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out num))
```

returns false
Whats is correct way to get number?Use other NumberStyles?Which?

The strNum is 01101250000000012300695162716

Comment: Can you show us the input?

Comment: What is the value of `strNum`?

Comment: "only leading and trailing spaces with a leading sign are allowed"

Comment: @CodeCaster-it is not - there is no solution there for my case

Comment: It's probably not the leading zero that's the problem - rather it's the limit of the range on uint.

Comment: Take a look to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293603/arbitrarily-large-integers-in-c-sharp/10293742#10293742). Basically you just need to use a BigInteger instead of an Int32.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cannot convert that string to an uint, try with a decimal

```
decimal num;
string strNum = "01101250000000012300695162716";
if (decimal.TryParse(strNum, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out num))
    Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
```

The [uint.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is defined as "4,294,967,295", your conversion fails for this reason