# Quickly get a rough estimate of the size of a BigInteger object?

Tags: c#, biginteger

I have a positive C# BigInteger. It could be very large. I want to get a very rough estimate of how big it is. If my estimate is wrong by (say) a factor of a thousand, that is fine.

I've tried the following. All are slowish (roughly 80k ticks on 3^1000000)

```
 int est1 = myBigInt.ToByteArray().Count();
 double est2 = BigInteger.Log10(myBigInt);
 double est3 = BigInteger.Log(myBigInt);
```

EDIT: By "size", I mean "numerical value", not "memory size."

Comment: `double est4 = 1000; ` Quick and rough =)

Comment: Talking seriously, you could try accessing it's private array's length with reflection. Reflection is slow, but definitely faster than math operations with million-digit values

Comment: If you don't mind reflection, `BigInteger.Length(myBigInt._Bits)` will do. Both members are internal, however. If you do mind reflection, and you have an upper range of some sort, you could try successive order of magnitude comparisons/binary search with `.CompareTo`, which should be much faster than `.Log`.

Comment: My favorite quip is that a googol (10^100) is more than everything. (For example, it is more than all photons in the observable universe, plus all atoms, plus anything you like.) Thus,if you have a real world application (and not a math quest for high numbers, or combinatorics) you will never need more than 330 bits or so to store a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from .NET Core 2.1 there's a [new API:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.getbytecount?view=netcore-2.1) `public int GetByteCount (bool isUnsigned = false);`

I hope we'll find it in the next versions of .NET Standard too.

Answer (score 7):

First *optimization* is to avoid LINQ here, `ToByteArray()` returns `byte[]` then you can directly use `Length` property:

```
int est = myBigInt.ToByteArray().Length;
```

This is, however, still sub-optimal because `ToByteArray()` clones internal buffer.For a **very huge** number you may even have better long-term performance using Reflection to read it:

```
var bits = typeof(BigInteger).GetField("_bits",
    BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
int size = ((uint[])bits.GetValue(myBigInt)).Length * sizeof(uint);
```

Note that property name and its type are implementation details and then subject to change, add proper unit testing...

Also note that `ToByteArray().Length` and internal buffer may be different (because internal buffer is a multiple of `sizeof(uint)` bytes and last array item may be empty, see internal `Length()` method implementation.)

All these said the [*funny* comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020533/quickly-get-a-rough-estimate-of-the-size-of-a-biginteger-object/40020793#comment67317840_40020533) from  Oleksandr Pshenychnyy is not wrong, unless you're working with enormous numbers and a +/-1000X (!!!) estimation is enough then you may use a constant size of 16 bytes (or 32 or 64...) It should be good enough to accommodate a very big integer (see also [Arbitrarily large integers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10293603/1207195))...

---

Comment: Porperty is named "_Bits". But you better access private field "_bits". Let's be dirty =)

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy you're right, fixed! If we have to break when they change implementation...;)

Comment: maybe not the most modern answer, but this helped me with my odd need. BTW - I think it might be "BindingFlags.Instance" instead of "BindingFlags.Default". (at least for me)

Answer (score 1):

Just ran across this thread..

As of .net 5, we now have [BigInteger.GetBitLength()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.getbitlength?view=net-6.0).

```
long bitSize = myBigInt.GetBitLength();
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, let us only consider positive BigInteger's as negative ones would need some additional conditions to calculate correctly (or can just negate and call these methods).  Also for negative values, the sign bit can be considered an extra bit or not depending on the context...

There are 2 reflection methods one a property, the other a field hence the capitalization issues people mention.  Anyway both can easily be done.  Here is the reflection only solution using code based on [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs) and it performs the fastest without a doubt even without caching the reflection fields/methods:

```
static int GetBitSizeReflection(BigInteger num)
{
  //uint[] bits = (uint[])typeof(BigInteger).GetField("_bits", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(num);
  uint[] bits = (uint[])typeof(BigInteger).GetProperty("_Bits", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(num);
  if (bits == null) {
    //int sign = (int)typeof(BigInteger).GetField("_sign", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(num);
    int sign = (int)typeof(BigInteger).GetProperty("_Sign", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(num);
    bits = new uint[] { (uint)(sign < 0 ? sign & int.MaxValue : sign) };
  }
  int uintLength = (int)typeof(BigInteger).GetMethod("Length", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(num, new object[] { bits });
  int topbits = (int)typeof(BigInteger).GetMethod("BitLengthOfUInt", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(num, new object[] { bits[uintLength - 1] });
  return (uintLength - 1) * sizeof(uint) * 8 + topbits;
```

For a `GetByteSize` routine - just use `GetBitSize / 8`.

If you do not want to go into such a hacky solution, then here is a repeated binary search method which should be generally far more efficient though in theory it could require additional comparisons for cases like 3 bits which 1, 2, 3 is faster than 1, 2, 4, 3 though a slight optimization could probably fix that case.  Also it only works for positive BigIntegers in this form:

```
static int GetBitSizeRecurseBinSearch(BigInteger num)
{ //instead of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4... use 0, 1, 3, 7, 15, etc
  int s = 0, t = 1, oldt = 1;
  if (t <= 0) return 0;
  while (true) {
    if ((BigInteger.One << (s + t)) <= num) { oldt = t; t <<= 1; }
    else if (t == 1) break;
    else { s += oldt; t = 1; }
  }
  return s + 1;
}
```

Unfortunately this is not very efficient but it certainly beats the naïve way of doing it.

```
static int GetBitSizeSlow(BigInteger num)
{
  int s = 0;
  while ((BigInteger.One << s) <= num) s++;
  return s;
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to stay within the framework and still be fast there is also a version that requires only some extra byte copying and is the next fastest after reflection:

```
static int GetBitSize(BigInteger num)
{
  byte[] bytes = num.ToByteArray();
  int size = bytes.Length;
  if (size == 0) return 0;
  int v = bytes[size - 1]; // 8-bit value to find the log2 of 
  if (v == 0) return (size - 1) * 8;
  int r; // result of log2(v) will go here
  int shift;
  r = (v > 0xF) ? 4 : 0; v >>= r;
  shift = (v > 0x3) ? 2 : 0; v >>= shift; r |= shift;
  r |= (v >> 1);
  return (size - 1) * 8 + r + 1;
}
```

Finally if really preferring binary search, first you will have to binary search a high value before binary searching normally:

```
static int GetBitSizeHiSearch(BigInteger num) //power of 2 search high, then binary search
{
  if (num.IsZero) return 0;
  int lo = 0, hi = 1;
  while ((BigInteger.One << hi) <= num) { lo = hi; hi <<= 1; }
  return GetBitSizeBinSearch(num, lo, hi);
}
static int GetBitSizeBinSearch(BigInteger num, int lo, int hi)
{
  int mid = (hi + lo) >> 1;
  while (lo <= hi) {
    if ((BigInteger.One << mid) <= num) lo = mid + 1;
    else hi = mid - 1;
    mid = (hi + lo) >> 1;
  }
  return mid + 1;
}
```

But the fastest is reflection, followed by getting the bytes, followed by binary search and then recursive binary search and finally the naïve method is the slowest which can be confirmed by profiling as the numbers get increasingly large (at 2^(2^20) it will certainly be obvious).

Also a special byte-optimized version which searches in multiples of 8s could be derived from any of these.