# c# how to add a million int character, how to add this without getting an error and getting the exact sum?

Tags: c#

how to add this without getting an error and getting the exact sum?

```
int a = 10000000000000;
int b = 10000000000000;

int c = a + b;

Messagebox.Show(Convert.ToString(c));
```

Comment: Use `long` instead of `int`. And if that's not enough, there's [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-5.0)

Comment: what if my numbers are larger than long? what should i do

Comment: In addition to `BigInteger`, you can take a look at [C# - Data Types (TutorialPoints)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm) and [Integral numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) and [Floating-point numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types).

Comment: @Crys - I told you - BigInteger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arbitrarily large integers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293603/arbitrarily-large-integers-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

A signed `int` can only represent numbers between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types).

You can represent larger range of numbers by using `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: i want to add numbers larger than long. how should i do it?

Comment: @Crys Use `decimal` else `System.Numerics.BigInteger` as suggested by @.Vilx: does it fit?

Answer (score 3):

`10000000000000` is a higher than `int` could hold. If you check the max value of int `int.MaxValue` you get `2147483647`. So you should use  `long` there and everything would be ok:

```
long a = 10000000000000;
long b = 10000000000000;

long c = a + b;

Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(c));
```

- Range of **int** is `[-2147483648,2147483647]`
- Range of **long** is `[-9223372036854775808,9223372036854775807]`